# Inter Process Communication 'URGENT' message types

Tags: c, linux, message-queue, inter-process-communicat

I've been going through [Beej's guides on inter process communication](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mq.html).

How would 'kirk.c' be modified to be able to send messages marked URGENT?
These URGENT messages would then be ignored by 'spock.c' and instead read by another program?

Comment: Questions that rely on linked content are vulnerable to becoming useless when the linked content is not available. Consider creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

In the file `kirk.c`, we can introduce an enum variable which will define the type of message to be sent. The structure `struct my_msgbuf` has a member variable `long mtype;`. One can initialise this to the message type before sending it to the receiver, in this case - `spock.c`.

The enum declaration:

```
enum msgType {
    URGENT = 0,
    NORMAL = 1
};
```

The above enum declaration can be put in a common header file to both `kirk.c` and `spock.c`.

The line `buf.mtype = 1; /* we don't really care in this case */` should be modified to `buf.mtype = URGENT; /* we don't really care in this case */`

In `spock.c`, following lines:

```
for(;;) { /* Spock never quits! */
    if (msgrcv(msqid, &buf, sizeof(buf.mtext), 0, 0) == -1) {
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("spock: \"%s\"\n", buf.mtext);
}
```

..will be modified to:

```
for(;;) { /* Spock never quits! */
    if (msgrcv(msqid, &buf, sizeof(buf.mtext), 0, 0) == -1) {
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (URGENT != buf.mtype) {
        printf("spock: \"%s\"\n", buf.mtext);
    }
}
```

So, spock will "process" (in this case, it just prints the data as a way of processing it) the message only if the message type is anything other than `URGENT`.

Comment: Rest in Peace, Spock 27/2/2015

Comment: declare `buf.mtype` as character array of size of your choice, but atleast having minimum number  of characters as required by the implementation.

replace `URGENT != buf.mtype` with `strncmp`